# Array of structure, designated initializer implication

Tags: c, initialization

I already know that:

1) array "partial initialization"

```
int array[10] = {1};
```

results in initialising array[0] with value 1, and all other array values with 0.

2) designated initializers

```
struct metadata {
    int val0;
    int val1;
    char *name;
};

void func(void){
    struct metadata my_metadata = { .val0 = 1 };
```

Results in initialising my_metadata.val0 with 1, my_metadata.val1 with 0 and my_metadata.name with NULL.

3) Here comes the question:

```
struct metadata {
    int val0;
    int val1;
    char *name;
};

void func(void){
    struct metadata my_metadata_array[2] = { {.val0 = 1} };
```

What will be the resulting operation of this ?

Bonus question 1: could someone point me to the reference documentation for "partial initialisation" (I do not know if it is a compiler extension or part of a specific standard version) ?

Bonus question 2: same than bonus question 1 for "designated initializers".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like in "partial initialization", the first `metadata` element will be initialized with `val0` element set to 1, everything else in that element and the second element will be default initialized (or the same as objects with static duration).

Bonus 1: It has been part of the standard for a while

C Standard 6.7.9-21:

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
>   of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
>   size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

Bonus 2: It is part of C99

C Standard 6.7.9-7

> If a designator has the form
>   . identifier
>   then the current object (defined below) shall have structure or union type and the
>   identifier shall be the name of a member of that type.

Answer (score 1):

Yes (you got the way of thinking fine), that's the result, it will set that variable to 1 and default initialize the rest of them.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct metadata {
    int val0;
    int val1;
    char *name;
};

int main(void){
    struct metadata my_metadata_array[2] = { {.val0 = 1} };
    printf("%d %d %s\n", my_metadata_array[0].val0,  my_metadata_array[0].val1,  my_metadata_array[0].name);
    printf("%d %d %s\n", my_metadata_array[1].val0,  my_metadata_array[1].val1,  my_metadata_array[1].name);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 0 (null)
0 0 (null)
```